# JavaScript replacing /r with <br/> is not working

Tags: javascript, replace

Now before some one marks this as a duplicate question, I have looked at the other posts with this problem and they have not solved my problem.

so I have a string that has some `\r` in it that need to be converted into `<br />`

But nothing is working

```
output = output.replace("\\r", "<br />");
```

is the closest thing that I got working was when my string has /r/r it will replace the first r with

every thing else I have tried literally has done nothing including

```
replace("\r", "<br />");
replace(/\\r/g, "<br />")
replace(/\r/g, "<br />")
replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

and a few others that I can not remember.
All those I found on other posts on stack over flow did not work. They did not even replace `\r`.

Here is an example of one of the strings Year 9 students to meet in their core subject groups at the following places at 8.30 am\r\r9A - OUTSIDE ESOL BLOCK\r9B - TECHNOLOGY COMPUTER ROOM\r9C - ESOL ROOM.\r\rPLEASE WEAR TRACKSUIT.\r its in an loop theres a bunch of different strings –

since people bleave it should be working here is a more brod view of the code

```
<script>

            TheOutput.innerText = "testbox";



            function nl2br (str) 
                {
                    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + '<br />' + '$2');
                }


            /* set up drag-and-drop event */
            function allowDrop(e) 
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            function handleDrop(e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                    var i,f;
                    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) 
                        {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            var name = f.name;

                            console.log("==== current file in file reader ====");
                            console.log(name);

                            reader.onload = function(e) 
                                {
                                    var data = e.target.result;

                                    /* if binary string, read with type 'binary' */
                                    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

                                    //----------------------------------
                                    /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
                                    //----------------------------------

                                    /*
                                    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                                    var address_of_cell = 'B3';

                                    /* Get worksheet 
                                    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

                                    /* Find desired cell 
                                    var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];

                                    /* Get the value 
                                    var desired_value = desired_cell.v; */





                                    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                                    sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) 
                                        { /* iterate through sheets */
                                            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];




                                            var cellCount = 0;
                                            var currentCell;
                                            var output;

                                            for (z in worksheet) 
                                                {
                                                    //z is the address of the cell
                                                    //y is the name of the worksheet

                                                    /* all keys that do not begin with "!" correspond to cell addresses */
                                                    if(z[0] === '!') continue;

                                                    console.log("==== JS Object ====");
                                                    console.log(worksheet[z].v);

                                                    console.log("==== JSON Object ====");
                                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(worksheet[z].v));

                                                    console.log("==== Other Stuff ====");
                                                    console.log(y + "!" + z + "=" + JSON.stringify(worksheet[z].v));


                                                    output = (JSON.stringify(worksheet[z].h)).toString();
                                                    output = output.replace(/"/g,"");
                                                    //(/\r/g, '<br/>')
                                                    //output = output.replace("\r", "<br/>");

                                                    output = output.replace(/\r/g, "<br />")

                                                    console.log("Grab output ans strip strings: " +output);

                                                    //output = nl2br (output);
                                                    //console.log("output after nl2br function: " +output);

                                                    console.log("======================");

                                                    //output = worksheet[z].w;

                                                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                                                    document.body.appendChild(div);
                                                    div.className = 'DivCells';


                                                    div.id = 'test'+ cellCount;


                                                    currentCell = div = document.getElementById('test'+ cellCount);
                                                    currentCell.innerHTML = output;

                                                    currentCell.style.left = '32px'; 
                                                    currentCell.style.top = ((cellCount+1)*10)+'px';


                                                    //TheOutput.innerText = output;

                                                    cellCount = cellCount + 1;


                                                }
                                                cellCount = 0;
                                        });

                                    //display the value
                                    //TheOutput.innerText = desired_value.toString();


                                    /*------------------------------------------
                                                END OF WORKBOOK STUFF
                                    --------------------------------------------*/

                                };

                            reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
                        }
                }
            //drop_dom_element.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

            //var workbook = XLSX.readFile('Kmaranotices.xlsx');




        </script>
```

Comment: Are you quite sure the string contains the characters you're trying to replace? At least one of the last three you list having tried should work.

Comment: Show us what `output` contains. E.g., we need a [mcve]. Also, if those last four were really `output = output.replace(...)`, show that, don't make people assume you did it based on the first one.

Comment: Maybe your *new-line* is `<p>` tag?

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla: To improve the question, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: On three occasions you mention your string contains `/r`(slash r). But in all your attempts your try to replace `\r`(*back*slash r).

Comment: If you use one of the things you say you tried on the string in that comment, it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7fupv7Lu/

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh40udds/

Comment: im telling you it dose not work in my code.
ill post my full code

Comment: *"ill post my full code"* No, again, post a *[mcve]*, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) so we can see it run live on-site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix it by creating an function

```
function nl2br (str) 
                {
                    //returns an string that replaces all the \r with new lines
                    return (str + '').replace(/\\r/g,'<br />');
                }
```

and then used it to process my output

```
output = (JSON.stringify(worksheet[z].h)).toString();
output = nl2br (output);
output = output.replace(/"/g,"");
```

this was a very weird issue and i am glad to of finally solved it.